# My triangle doesn't render when I use OpenGL Core Profile 3.2

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I have a Cocoa (OSX) project that is currently very simple, I'm just trying to grasp the general concepts behind using OpenGL. I was able to get a triangle to display in my view, but when I went to write my vertex shaders and fragment shaders, I realized I was running the legacy OpenGL core profile. So I switched to the OpenGL 3.2 profile by setting the properties in the pixel format of the view in question before generating the context, but now the triangle doesn't render, even without my vertex or fragment shaders.

I have a controller class for the view that's instantiated in the nib. On `-awakeFromNib` it sets up the pixel format and the context:

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attr[] =
{
    NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile, NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
    0
};
NSOpenGLPixelFormat *glPixForm = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attr];
[self.mainView setPixelFormat:glPixForm];
self.glContext = [self.mainView openGLContext];
```

Then I generate the VAO:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);
```

Then the VBO:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

`g_vertex_buffer_data`, the actual data for that buffer is defined as follows:

```
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
};
```

Here's the code for actually drawing:

```
[_glContext setView:self.mainView];
[_glContext makeCurrentContext];
glViewport(0, 0, [self.mainView frame].size.width, [self.mainView frame].size.height);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
                      0,
                      3,
                      GL_FLOAT,
                      GL_FALSE,
                      0,
                      (void*)0
                      );
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glFlush();
```

This code draws the triangle fine if I comment out the `NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile, NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,` in the `NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute` array, but as soon as I enable OpenGL Core Profile 3.2, it just displays black. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: This issue still happens whether I turn my vertex and fragment shaders on or not, but here are my shaders in case it is helpful:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 150

in vec3 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position.xyz = position;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 150

out vec3 color;

void main() {
    color = vec3(1,0,0);
}
```

And right before linking the program, I make this call to bind the attribute location:

```
glBindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "position");
```

EDIT 2:

I don't know if this helps at all, but I just stepped through my program, running `glGetError()` and it looks like everything is fine until I actually call `glDrawArrays()`, then it returns `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. I'm trying to figure out why this could be occurring, but still having no luck.

Comment: Try make your triangle at `-1` on your Z-axis.  That could be the problem.  Also mind if you post your shaders and also your MVP matrix too?

Comment: It actually doesn't make a difference whether I'm using using my vertex/fragment shaders or not, but I'll put them up in just a second. And I don't think I have an MVP matrix.

Comment: Oh, and I just tried setting the vertices to -1 on the z-axis and it's still happening.

Comment: Wow, I'm stumped.  From what I see your code seems fine.  Try use `#import <OpenGL/gl3.h>` instead and see if that's the problem.  If not, try check if OpenGL is reporting any errors using [this](http://pastebin.com/ydi01kVG).

Comment: You can also run it with OpenGL Profiler and see if it produces any errors along the way. I've found that some VAR errors don't get reported by `glGetError()`.

Comment: Using glGetError() is helping me isolate the issue, but I still haven't figured out why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out, and it's sadly a very stupid mistake on my part.

I think the issue is that you need a vertex shader and a fragment shader when using 3.2 core profile, you can't just render without them. The reason it wasn't working with my shaders was...wait for it...after linking my shader program, I forgot to store the programID in the ivar in my class, so later when I call glUseProgram() I'm just calling it with a zero parameter.

I guess one of the main sources of confusion was the fact that I expected the 3.2 core profile to work without any vertex or fragment shaders.

Comment: You should use glGetError to detect invalid operations